# PHP Notice: Undefined offset occurs seemingly unpredicably

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code:

```
$j = explode(",",$i);
//print_r($j);
$list2[ $j[0] ] = array( $reportname." uniques" => $j[3], $reportname." rev" => $j[6] );
```

If I comment out the print_r statement, I get the following errors:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset:  3 in /home/martin/php/class.php on line 200
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset:  6 in /home/martin/php/class.php on line 200
```

If I leave in the print_r statement, I do not get errors and I can see that $j does have elements 3 and 6:

```
Array
(
    [0] => xxxxx
    [1] => 2013-06-10
    [2] => 2013-07-09
    [3] => 48
    [4] => 81
    [5] => 37
    [6] => 1.95
)
```

Has anyone got any idea why this is happening? The problem seemed to start occurring when I made an unrelated modification to my code. Is php low on memory or something?

Comment: Can you print the variable `$i` and show the output? Try multiple times to make sure it is consistent.

Comment: Obviously, when it occurs, $j only has (at most) indexes 0->2 available. e.g. whatever source you're getting this explodable text from doesn't always have the proper format and your code simply assumes there will ALWAYS be 7 elements after explode() runs.

Comment: @Thomas Potaire:  `code`xxxx,2013-07-03,2013-07-11,82,11,3,0.03Array
(
    [0] => xxxx
    [1] => 2013-07-03
    [2] => 2013-07-11
    [3] => 82
    [4] => 11
    [5] => 3
    [6] => 0.03
)

Comment: @MarcB: you were right--by adding the code below I discovered that on the 937th iteration of the loop, $i is empty `code`
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($list as $i) {
            $j = explode(",",$i);
            //print_r($i);
            //print_r($j);
            $count++;
            if (!isset($j[3])) {
                echo "j3 not set:".$count."\r\n";
                print_r($i);
                print_r($j);
            }
            $list2[ $j[0] ] = array( $reportname." uniques" => $j[3], $reportname." rev" => $j[6] );    
        }